# How to fix Timeago errors

Tags: php

I have a time ago function in php which i use to return if the user is online or when the user was last seen.

```
function tj_online_last($ptime) {
    $estimate_time = time() - strtotime($ptime);
    // if time diff is less than 1 minute then user is online
    if ($estimate_time < 60) {
        return 'online';
    }
    $condition = array(
                12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60   => 'year',
                30 * 24 * 60 * 60        => 'month',
                24 * 60 * 60             => 'day',
                60 * 60                  => 'hour',
                60                       => 'minute',
                1                        => 'second',
    );
    foreach($condition as $secs => $str) {
        $d = $estimate_time / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1) {
            $r = round($d);
            return $r.' '.$str.($r > 1 ? 's' : '').' ago';
        } 
    }
}
```

Now the problem here when the user has not been logged into his account for the first time the time value is 'NULL'. I would like to return 'never' instead of the annoying '48 years ago' because I am not able to handle the error.

Comment: Then `return 'never';`, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...
When user first time login then it's last entry is null so you need to check condition `if` last date is empty `then` `return 'never';`

```
function tj_online_last($ptime) {
    if(strtotime($ptime) <= 0){
        return 'never';
    }
    $estimate_time = time() - strtotime($ptime);
    // if time diff is less than 1 minute then user is online
    if ($estimate_time < 60) {
        return 'online';
    }
    $condition = array(
                12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60   => 'year',
                30 * 24 * 60 * 60        => 'month',
                24 * 60 * 60             => 'day',
                60 * 60                  => 'hour',
                60                       => 'minute',
                1                        => 'second',
    );
    foreach($condition as $secs => $str) {
        $d = $estimate_time / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1) {
            $r = round($d);
            return $r.' '.$str.($r > 1 ? 's' : '').' ago';
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain the answer in details that how your code will work and where he did the mistake.

Comment: Thank you sir, just what I needed it worked as expected. I never thought that way